# Adobe Acrobat split window horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, window, preview, split-window

I'm looking to scroll through and compare the same multi-page document side by side in Adobe Acrobat. Right now I'm forced to open the file in Apple Preview and Acrobat side by side which is just plain annoying. The catch is that I need to independently scroll on each side of the "split". I'm able to use Window-Split which accomplishes everything I need except the split is vertical instead of horizontal. Any assistance would be much appreciated.